# Stack Level Too Deep: Spree Admin - Product Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, spree

I'm getting a Stack Level Too Deep error in my Production environment for spree 2.3.0.

It occurs when I try to go to the product images index page in the Admin panel. This error is not happening in Development, only production on Ninefold. The error does not occur when I run the app locally in Production mode. I can seem to trace what is causing it. I have not changed any of the default core functionality in Spree related to Product Images. The images render fine on the front-end.

I'm using paperclip and aws. At one point there was no error on production. However, I've check all my commits and cant pinpoint what changed that is causing this issue. I've added other gems, but none of the gems conflict with the paperclip gems or its dependency, which was my my guess at what might be causing this.

here is the production log error.

```
+0000
I, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.691119 #26116] INFO -- : Processing by Spree::Admin::ImagesController#index as HTML
I, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.691252 #26116] INFO -- : Parameters: {"product_id"=>"black-string-tie-halter-top-with-printed-neck-binding"}
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.693443 #26116] DEBUG -- : Cache read: spree/app_configuration/redirect_https_to_http
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.693920 #26116] DEBUG -- : Cache read: spree/backend_configuration/locale
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.695806 #26116] DEBUG -- : [1m[36mSpree::Preference Load (0.7ms)[0m [1mSELECT "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/backend_configuration/locale' LIMIT 1[0m
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.695979 #26116] DEBUG -- : Cache write: spree/backend_configuration/locale
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.696566 #26116] DEBUG -- : Cache read: spree/app_configuration/allow_ssl_in_production
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.696881 #26116] DEBUG -- : Cache read: spree/app_configuration/check_for_spree_alerts
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.697171 #26116] DEBUG -- : Cache read: spree/app_configuration/last_check_for_spree_alerts
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.699099 #26116] DEBUG -- : [1m[35mSpree::User Load (0.5ms)[0m SELECT "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" WHERE "spree_users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "spree_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.702026 #26116] DEBUG -- : [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "spree_roles" INNER JOIN "spree_roles_users" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_roles_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "spree_roles"."name" = 'admin'[0m [["user_id", 1]]
I, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.706068 #26116] INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
F, [2015-01-11T22:02:28.706732 #26116] FATAL -- : 
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:629
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

update - Full Stack Trace in Production Environment:

```
SystemStackError in Spree::Admin::ImagesController#index
stack level too deep

Rails.root: /var/www/apps/11829/releases/dbeebbeebaf8ac5fa580e0fd192ad9fc06e7ce4b

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:629
```

Comment: The stack trace is not clear enough. Can you turn on full stack trace in `environments/production.rb` and paste it here?

Comment: @kasperite added to the question. Doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Can you run your application in production locally? `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`?

Comment: @RyanBigg Yes. I do not get the error running locally in production.

Comment: @RyanBigg I'm deployed on Ninefold in actual production mode where I'm seeing the error. BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after going through all the gems I installed I finally found the issue.

It was an alias_method in the Spree::Admin::ImagesController decorator that caused the Stack Level Too Deep error.